# Как исправить сортировку полученных данных из БД?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby

Есть такой запрос:

```
posts_and_images = current_user.posts_and_images.select('DISTINCT ON (post_id) post_id, id, user_id, image_id, position').order(:post_id, position: :desc)
```

Нужно отсортировать полученные данные только по position, но на деле сейчас полученные данные сортируются по post_id, а сортировка по position игнорируется.

Притом если схитрить таким образом:

```
.order(position: :desc, post_id: :desc)
```

То ошибка:

> PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must
>   match initial ORDER BY expressions LINE 1

Точно такая же ошибка, если вообще не указывать "post_id" в ORDER. "post_id" должно всегда находиться в ORDER и всегда должно быть первым, так как используется DISTINCT.

Как исправить?

Comment: Если коротко, то [устройство `DISTINCT ON` не даёт так сделать](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9795660/2076787).

Comment: @D-side это я уже понял :) тогда как быть?

Comment: @D-side единственное, что мне пришло сейчас в голову - это вот этот костыль `current_user.posts_and_images.sort_by { |item| item.position }.reverse.uniq! { |item| item.post_id }`. Но тут даже я понимаю, что решение не гуд, ибо записи вынимаются из таблицы все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат запроса с `DISTINCT ON` всегда будет отсортирован в первую очередь по полям, указанным в `DISTINCT ON` из-за уже упомянутого ограничения. Избавиться от этого нельзя.

Можно только сортировать результаты этого запроса постфактум. Можно это сделать в Ruby, но можно и на уровне БД:

```
Модель.select(Arel.star).from(подзапрос, :алиас).order(:position)
#      выбрать   всё*     из  подзапроса "алиас" с сортировкой по "position"
```

Скорее всего, базе сортировка удастся быстрее, чем Ruby. Но стоит подумать, не лучше ли показывать что-то другое, что проще достать. Например, можно ли модифицировать данные таким образом, чтобы `DISTINCT ON` был не нужен.

Скажем, можно хранить в посте id какой-то "избранной записи", которые доставать с помощью банального `JOIN` к постам. Уникальность по постам будет вытекать из структуры данных: условие на равенство первичного ключа некоему значению может дать не более одной записи. И в каждом посте может быть не более одного значения. Так-то.

---

** Это базонезависимый `*` (хоть он вроде и везде одинаковый и можно использовать просто `.select("*")`). ActiveRecord строит запросы при помощи Arel, и это его литерал для wildcard.*

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. И за поданные хорошие идеи. Что-то в этом есть, буду пробовать.